# How to add a radio button to an already existing Group Box in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, groupbox

I am working on an Excel sheet that was made by someone else. There are some radio buttons in a group box linked to a macro. I have made the changes into the macro and want to add another radio button in the group box. How can I do that? When I add the new button, it is working separately from the other buttons in the group.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you manually add the radio button in discussion? Do you use a piece of code? Show us at least the macro you changed, to make the question having more relevance...

Comment: I was to manually add the radio button. As for the change in macro, I changed "If A = True Then ...' to 'If A = True or If B = True Then...". The button for A already exists in the group box. I am trying to add the button for B. The main goal is that if B is selected, some files that are being saved on the drive won't be saved.

Comment: What A and B should mean? Linked cells to the radio button? Radio button names? Or what? Then, what type are them? Form controls or ActiveX controls?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not answer the clarification questions, please proceed in the next way, according to the radio button type:

1. Form type radio buttons:

a. You firstly need to insert a `Group Box` (Developer Tab - Design Mode - Group Box

b. Drag the Form radio buttons on it.

All radio buttons placed on such a group box will act in the same group

2. ActiveX radio buttons:

a. You simply drag them on the sheet.

b. Press `Properties` from Developer tab `Controls` group and set **the same group name**  (string) in `GroupName` property.

The radio buttons having the same `GroupName` will act as a group.

Since you do not say anything about the group boxes, most probably you are using ActiveX radio buttons. So, check the `GroupName` property of existing one in the group you need to add a new one and use the same.